# Simple conditional unexpectedly fails in bash if statement

Tags: bash

I've spent an embarrassingly long time trying to understand why the second conditional in the "foo" script below fails but the first one succeeds.

Please note:

- The current directory contains two files: bar and foo.
- All three strings $s1, $s2 and $s3 are equal according to hexdump.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Session: (Running on a Centos7 host):

```
>ls
bar  foo
>cat foo
#!/bin/bash

s1="bar foo"
s2="bar foo"
s3=`ls`

echo -n $s1 | hexdump -C
echo -n $s2 | hexdump -C
echo -n $s3 | hexdump -C

if [ "$s1" = "$s2" ]; then  # True
    echo s1 = s2
fi

if [ "$s1" = "$s3" ]; then  # NOT true! Why?
    echo s1 = s3
fi

>foo
00000000  62 61 72 20 66 6f 6f                              |bar foo|
00000007
00000000  62 61 72 20 66 6f 6f                              |bar foo|
00000007
00000000  62 61 72 20 66 6f 6f                              |bar foo|
00000007
s1 = s2
>
```

Comment: Note, however, that `s3=\`ls\`` is not the way to read a list of file names into a variable. Read [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) before you start writing any real code based on your experiments here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote the variables when echoing.

```
echo -n "$s3" | hexdump -C
```

You'll see a newline between the file names, as `ls` uses `-1` when the output is redirected.

Answer (score 2):

Your demo would be more convincing with `echo -n "$s1"` etc.  That would show that there's a newline in the middle of `s3` where there's a space in `s1` and `s2`.  The `echo` without the double quotes mangles the newline into a space (and generally each sequence of one or more white space characters in the string into a single space).

Given:

```
#!/bin/bash

s1="bar foo"
s2="bar foo"
s3=`ls`

echo -n "$s1" | hexdump -C
echo -n "$s2" | hexdump -C
echo -n "$s3" | hexdump -C

if [ "$s1" = "$s2" ]; then  # True
    echo s1 = s2
fi

if [ "$s1" = "$s3" ]; then  # NOT true because s3 contains a newline!
    echo s1 = s3
fi
```

I get:

```
$ sh foo
00000000  2d 6e 20 62 61 72 20 66  6f 6f 0a                 |-n bar foo.|
0000000b
00000000  2d 6e 20 62 61 72 20 66  6f 6f 0a                 |-n bar foo.|
0000000b
00000000  2d 6e 20 62 61 72 0a 66  6f 6f 0a                 |-n bar.foo.|
0000000b
s1 = s2
$ bash foo
00000000  62 61 72 20 66 6f 6f                              |bar foo|
00000007
00000000  62 61 72 20 66 6f 6f                              |bar foo|
00000007
00000000  62 61 72 0a 66 6f 6f                              |bar.foo|
00000007
s1 = s2
$
```